# How to generate random IP with groovy

Tags: groovy

How to generate random IP with groovy : 
I can generate a string, but can't figure out a fast way to IP.
org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random

Comment: Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get the most out of StackOverflow.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You should provide us some code (stackoverflow isn't a service for developing your applications).

Answer (score 2):

If you just need random IP addresses, why not just something simple like:

```
def random = new Random()

(0..3).collect { random.nextInt(255) }.join('.')
```

You will end up with something like:

```
10.222.40.74
```

Comment: thank a lot, that solved my issue.

Comment: Excellent answer.